# Oracle: formatting Numbers

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have an Oracle column defined as `NUMBER(10,5)` I want to change it in a String with this format 00000 WITH 2 decimals, e.g. : 3.46 -> 00346

I am using this function

```
LPAD(replace( TO_CHAR(ptd.trf_phr ,'999.99'), '.', '' ), 5, '0')
```

but for 8,24 I get  82, not 00824

Comment: With your version 8.24 does go to 00824. Why does 3.46 to go 00345 rather than 00346?

Comment: copy & paste error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

messy but it works

> select lpad(replace(replace( TO_CHAR(ptd.trf_phr,'999.99'), '.', ''
>   ),' ',''),5,'0') from dual